# Android crash logs default location

Tags: android, crash-reports

Is there any way that I can get crash logs from a device which is signed with a public key, but not uploaded in android market? I need a way to get crash logs from a specific device to see why my application is crashing on it. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various frameworks for this. ACRA is one of them (http://code.google.com/p/acra/). Another that I frequently use is Bugsense (http://bugsense.com/). There are more also, but I think these two will be perfect for you!

Hope this helps!

Update:

In case you don't want to add any external library, you have to do it by your own. This means that Android in general has a mechanism to catch all uncaught exceptions. This is http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29.

There you can catch all uncaught exceptions and handle them as you wish (write to a file, send them, etc). All there libraries internally use this mechanism, but provide a wrapper to the user.

Comment: I saw a couple of libraries/applications which are getting the crash logs, but is there any way without including these jar's/applications on the device to get the logs. I mean to get them from it's default storage path or something like that. Or I have to include/download another application which will do that for me?

Comment: What if the process crashes ? I saw this log line on my device: 09-04 16:32:14.242: I/dalvikvm(217): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Answer (score 0):

One option is installing and running a LogCat application (e.g. aLogcat) on the target phone. This can capture all logcat output - including exceptions - for the overall system and/or the app in question - using a filter.